# Finding when quotient rule can't be used

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem:

[image]

My thought process has led to the following conclusions:

1. $f(x)$ must be a horizontal line, so $f'(x) = 0$
2. Due to $f'(x) = 0$, $h'(x) = 0$, so $h(x)$ is also a horizontal line.

From here, I was not able to make any other deductions, so I looked at the answer:

> The answer is E) $2$ because no quotient rule so $g(x)$ must be non-zero constant.

I don't understand why quotient rule can't be used here. Can someone explain this vague answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you deduced that $f(x)$ must be constant. But the answer is $2$ since the quotient rule says that $h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)\cdot g(x)-f(x)\cdot g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$. But it is given that this expression equals to $\frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}$. That implies that $g'(x)=0$ so $g(x)$ is constant. Since $g(5)=2$, we get $g(x)=2$ for all $x$.

Comment: Could you explain how it implies that g'(x) = 0?

Comment: Note that $f'\cdot g^2-f\cdot g'\cdot g = f'\cdot g^2$. Hence $f\cdot g'\cdot g=0$ and since $f$ is never zero we deduce that $g'\cdot g=0$. Note that $h$ is defined as the quotient $f/g$ which implies that $g$ is never zero. Hence $g'\cdot g=0$ implies $g'=0$.

Comment: I get it now, is it right to assume g(x) is a horizontal line?

Comment: Yes, $g'(x)=0$ implies $g(x)$ is constant, i.e. its graph is a horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

You are given that $\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}=g'=\frac{f'}{g}$.

Therefore

$$-\frac{fg'}{g^2}=0$$

Since $f$ is never zero as implied by $f<0$, it must be that $g'=0$.

Therefore $g$ is constant. Since you are given the value $g(5)=2$, then $g(x)=2$ for all $x$.

Comment: Could you assume f'(x) = 0 because f is never zero?

Comment: @Pablo No, you can't - for example, $f$ might be $-x^2 - 1$, which is always negative but has nonzero derivative almost everywhere.